# PHP Shorthand Ternary not behaving as expected

Tags: php

Introduced in PHP 5.3, the shorthand ternary operator should work like this:

```
$result = 'foo' ?: 'bar';
```

should return `foo`. However, on my live server (PHP 5.4.26), the result is `bar`.

A full ternary operator syntax works fine.

```
$test = 'foo';
$result = $test ? $test : 'bar';
```

returns `foo` correctly. Both syntaxes are fine on my dev server (PHP 5.3.10).

Is there any way this could be disabled somehow? Any suggestions?

Changing all the instances to the full systax is undesirable - there's a significant number in an external library (Amazon AWS SDK).

**Correction:**

```
$result = 'foo' ?: 'bar';
```

DOES have the correct result on both servers, but

```
$test = 'foo';
$result = $test ?: 'bar';
```

Incorrectly returns `bar` on the live server. Which is even wierder...

Comment: `$result = 'foo' ? 'foo': 'bar';`

Comment: Can't reproduce in any version of PHP: http://3v4l.org/GaNVW. Are you 2000% sure that this is so? If so, you should open an official PHP bug with as much information as possible.

Comment: Absolutely sure: testing using $test = 'foo';
$result = $test ?: 'bar';
var_dump($result);

Comment: And I can't reproduce on anything other than this one server either!

Comment: as deceze said, sounds like a possible PHP bug. If you're sure it's not caused by anything else you should report it on [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net/)

Comment: Found https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66524 which at the very least I can contribute to.